# Sioux City OxBow Washing Machine Box

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have a Sioux City Oxbox installed in my wall for the hot/cold water valves that go to my washing machine. I need to replace the hammer arrestors that came already installed on the valves but not sure if I can replace them individually or if this entire box has to be replaced. Not sure if the arrestors can be unscrewed from the water valve or if they are permanently affixed.

Comment: Photo please. (My intuition says they are removable. But I'd also ask why those are the target for maintenance.)